# Two targets and two Localizable.Strings (one base)

Tags: xcode, swift, target, localizable.strings

I have a simple problem and I can't figure out how to make it work.

- I have two targets:

  1. TargetApp1
  2. TargetApp2
- I have two Localizable.strings:

  1. For translation for a second language.
  2. For different names (on both languages), only for TargetApp2.

Example: 
I have a button, a text, or something. On each app it should be different.

- TargetApp1: en: "Store" - lg: "STORE_"
- TargetApp2: en: "Dealer" - lg: "DEALER_"

I tried keeping the first Localizable.strings for both targets and making the second Localizable.strings for the second target only. The problem is that only ONE Localizable.strings is loaded at a time. I wanna know how to make the TargetApp2 make both Localizable.strings complement each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, you'll need to give your `Localizable.strings` files different names and then use [NSLocalizedStringFromTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedStringFromTable), otherwise, as you've discovered, they'll conflict and only one is used at runtime.

e.g.

- Leave your Target1's `Localizable.strings` as it is
- Rename Target2's `Localizable.strings` to `Extra.strings`
- Anywhere that uses a string from the second table, use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, @"Extra", comment)`

I first encountered this problem when adding the Amazon AWS library which contains its own `Localizable.strings` which would arbitrarily be used instead of mine. However, because there are only a few strings in that file, it appeared as if localisation just wasn't working. That was a fun 2 days debugging!

---

### Swift

The `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` doesn't exist with that exact name in Swift. Instead the `table` is an optional parameter in `NSLocalizedString`

```
func NSLocalizedString(
    key: String,
    tableName: String? = default,
    bundle: NSBundle = default,
    value: String = default,
    #comment: String) -> String
```

With Swift, you'll just need to change your `NSLocalizedString(key: key, comment: "")` to `NSLocalizedString(key: key, table:"Extra" comment: "")` for the affected strings.

Comment: I am actually programming in Swift. NSLocalizedStringFromTable doesn't exist in swift.

Comment: No, not by that name. If memory serves me correctly, "table" is an optional parameter in `NSLocalizedString` in Swift.

Comment: What is _value_ parameter useful for? I did not find any description in Apple's documentation.

Comment: If you provide a value, this is used as a default if no translation for the key is provided. Without this parameter, the key itself is used as the default